# Why are token purchases on Rinkeby test net showing up on etherscan but the tokens not showing up in Ethereum Wallet?

Tags: wallets, tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan

The Ethereum Wallet is synced to the network, and it is the most up to date version. But the address that was the beneficiary of the tokens when purchased does not have any tokens in the account on Ethereum Wallet.

The tokens are transferred according to etherscan though and the funds are forwarded to the correct address receiving the funds in the ethereum wallet.

I really have no idea why this is, and can't find any explanation on Github. I appreciate any help on fixing this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you did not add the token to the Ethereum Wallet yet.

Open it up, click on "Contracts", then scroll down to the "Custom Tokens" section and if its not listed there, click on "Watch Token", fill in the token's contract address, it should fill in the rest automatically, then click "OK" and you should see your balance for that token.